# Claims and query data rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

In this article (http://www.codemag.com/Article/0001308101) it is suggested that claims can be used to grand/deny certain types of access to data rows.

To be more specific: the article mentions:

```
public void ProtectedMethod()
{
    ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("bankaccount|1234", "Read"); 
    // Perform protected task.
}
```

In my opinion (please correct me if I am wrong) this suggests that access to data rows (in this case bank account numbers) can be managed with claims.

So far I get the picture and find this doable (well I think).

Now, imagine I want to query a list of all the account numbers a user may access. In a non-claimed-based scenario we could query the database like:

```
var list = db.BankAccounts.Where(c => c.UserId == userId);
```

in a claim based scenario it would mean something like (just an example scenario):

```
var list = db.BankAccounts.Where(c => 
    ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("bankaccount|1234", "Read"))
```

But this doesn't really feel right.

Am I missing a crucial part? Or is it not really a good idea to protect access to data rows in this way?

**UPDATE**

After reading Wiktor Zychla's answer and comments I am still confused: at the moment the claims are stored in a claims table. The BankAccounts are stored in another table.

So basically I see this as options:

1) Query the bank accounts and join with the claims table (or cached data).

But I am still not sure this is the right approach.

Comment: I guess what you miss is that although physically claims are stored somewhere (in a table), upon authentication they are stored in a cookie that establishes a local session for a user. You retrieve a claim from there, not from the table to use it in a current user session.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Okay, I was missed that one indeed. I'll have to review my project-setup. I thought I could use claims as a 'per-row' kind of authorization. But adding cookie-data for "read/write/delete/etc" per data-row will blow up the cookie quite quick. Thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claims are just pairs of name-value. It is perfectly valid to have a custom claim for user id.

This means that you don't have to stick with this `CheckAccess` method. Rather, find a needed claim (user name, user id, whatever) and use its value like you would use the id in the former example.

Comment: So, if I am not mistaken that would suggest a database join query to the claims table?

Comment: No, a where clause using a claim value. It doesn't matter where is the original source of the claim as long as you have its value.